# How to pass all arguments as collection to another function and not as single argument?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that accepts any number and kind of arguments, so no specific parameter has been defined. This function should call another function passing all arguments.

The problem is that I can pass "arguments" in order to include all arguments but in this case it will work like a single argument and not the way we expect arguments to work.

An example:

The main function:

```
function handleCall() {
   // let's call a sub-function
   // and pass all arguments (my question is how this is handled the right way)
   function callSubFunction( arguments );
}

function callSubfunction( userid, customerid, param) {
   // passed arguments are now 
   alert( 'userid = ' + userid );

   // this will not work, you have to use arguments[2]
   alert( param );
  }

The example call:

handleCall( 1029, 232, 'param01' );
```

Using the approach above, all arguments will be stored in "userid" as pseudo-array and items can be accessed e.g. arguments[2] but not using the parameter name "param".

In ColdFusion, the solution for such stuff is the parameter "argumentCollection", this way you can pass parameters stored in a structure without being converted to a single argument with the type struct containing all key/values.

How can I achieve the same with JavaScript?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [the `.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) to call a function and pass the arguments as a set.

```
callSubFunction.apply( this, arguments );
```

The first argument will set the value of `this` in the `allSubFunction` method. I just set it to the current `this` value. The second is the collection of arguments to send.

So your `handleCall()` function will look like:

```
function handleCall() {
     //set the value of "this" and pass on the arguments object
    callSubFunction.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

It isn't required that you send an `Arguments` object. You could send an `Array` of arguments if the circumstance required.

Comment: how to do it in ES6 function?

Comment: The link to the documentation here is **dead**. [My edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5041911), which correctly **fixed** the links, was rejected by two users with *the same* copy-pasted message about "readability", despite the message not affecting visible text. (I suspect they were farming/botting for site rep.) In the meantime, here is a working link to MDN's `Function.prototype.apply()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 78):

If you want to do the same with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), you can use the following:

```
function handleCall(...args) {
    callSubFunction(...args);
}
```

Comment: For typescript, we can extract the type of our function parameters and use that to type the rest args:
type handleCallParams = Parameters<typeof handleCall>;

Comment: That's the good stuff!

Comment: For typescript with a constructor and a call to super, you can use `ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseClass>`

Answer (score 1):

Use apply like so:

```
function Foo()
{
    Bar.apply(this, arguments);
}

function Bar(a, b)
{
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```